# Is it right expression meaningwise? (Overestimate the value of the flat?)

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> The expression:

- She overestimates the value of her flat.

> Context:

Actual highest price of her flat is $50

According to her assessment, the price is $100

> Question:

Is it right expression according to the description?

Comment: **Overestimates the value** and **inflates the value** are good, as the answers suggest.  **She is overvaluing her flat** is another possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the meaning of "overestimate" is "to estimate (something) to be better, larger, or more important than it really is," yes the sentence "She overestimates the value of her flat" is correct in the given context.

Answer (score 2):

You could also say:

> She is **inflating** the value of her flat.

[*inflate*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inflate):

> 3. *verb*
>      If someone inflates the amount or effect of something, they say it is bigger, better, or more important than it really is, usually so that they can profit from it.